# Disable input field while searching and set focus on completion

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an input field and on typing I want to search for items and also disable the text field while doing the search in background so that no more letters can type in that input, but on completion of search function, the focus should be the search input field so that user can start typing.

**Html:**

```
<input [disabled]="(displayLoader > 0)" [ngModel]="''" (ngModelChange)="updateData($event)" class="form-control-search" placeholder="Search"/>
```

**component:**

```
updateData(event) {
   this.displayLoader = 1
   //search function
   //on completion
   this.displayLoader = 0; 
}
```

Here I used disabled, but on completion it is not focusing the input field and also cannot type until the user manually click the input field.

Comment: Are you trying to disable the input field while the search data is fetched by service call ?

Comment: as per his description, he wants to disable textbox while search perform in back end and on completion it should focus

Comment: @Abrar It's unclear to me, as one who is unfamiliar with typescript, as to why that tag addition is necessary. Would you mind clarifying, which feature exclusive to TypeScript and not available to JavaScript is used here? What is it that makes this example incompatible with a more vanilla Angular on JS configuration?

Comment: Yes as @SandipPatel told, I want to disable the search field while background data fetching is happening.

Comment: Thanks all for the response, Focus is working properly with the angular2-focus. here I want focus and disabled together which is not working

Answer (score 2):

try this code. does this help.
**html**

```
<input [disabled]="(displayLoader > 0)" [ngModel]="''" #focusable (ngModelChange)="updateData($event,focusable)" class="form-control-search" placeholder="Search"/>
```

**component**

```
 updateData(event,el) {
       this.displayLoader = 1
       //search function
       //on completion
       this.displayLoader = 0; 
    el.focus();
    }
```

Comment: This one I have already tried, But that focus is not working properly. ie we have to manually click that input field to start typing. Focusing to the same element is not working

Comment: see here may be helpful, https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-set-focus-element/

Comment: Thanks man, Focus is working properly with the angular2-focus. here I want focus and disabled together which is not working.

Comment: Disabled seems already working for me, but I couldn't type anyway after that.